# How to prove Neumann series doesnt converge when spectral radius > 1?

Tags: normed-spaces, spectral-theory, spectral-radius

For an operator $T \in B(X)$, its spectral radius is $$r(T) = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \|T^n\|^{1/n}$$
and the Neumann series is 
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}T^n.$$

If $r(T)>1$, I can show that series is not absolutely convergent $\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\|T^n\| \rightarrow \infty\right)$ but I'm not sure how to show it isn't convergent, i.e. $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}T^n \notin B(X)$. It would certainly suffice to show that $$\left\lbrace \sum_{n=0}^{k} T^n \right \rbrace_{k=1}^\infty$$ is not Cauchy or not bounded but I cant think of any appropriate lower bounds. Is there a general strategy for proving a series in a normed space is not convergent?

Comment: $r(T) > 1$ implies $||T^n|| \not \to 0$, so $\sum T^n$ can't converge

Comment: why does $\|T^n\| \nrightarrow 0$ mean that $\sum T^n$ can't converge? Can we bound $\|\sum T^n\|$ from below with the norm of one of the $T^n$'s?

Comment: it's just a very basic fact of life that $\sum_n a_n$ converges implies $|a_n| \to 0$. For a proof, um, just note that $||T^{N+1}|| = ||\sum_{n \le N+1} T^n-\sum_{n \le N} T^n|| \to 0$